# How to send/archive a row of data from one sheet to another through trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var rows = r.getRow();
  var cell = s.getRange(rows, r.getColumn());

  if (s.getName() == "Sheet" && r.getColumn() == 2 && cell.getValue() == "Archive" || cell.getValue() == "Cancel" || cell.getValue() == "Canceled" || cell.getValue() == "Cancelled") { // "Sheet" is original sheet, 2 is column to search for trigger
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Archive"); // "Sheet Archive" is the 2nd/target sheet
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(rows, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(rows);
  Logger.log(target);
  }
```

I would like for a way to send a row of data from a sheet (Sheet) to another (Sheet Archive). If "Archive" is written in the 2nd column of a row, it sends the data to the archive sheet.

I want the data to stack one row after another. Say I archive row #20 in Sheet #1, I want it to send the data to row #9. If I archive row #21, 22, then 30, 31, etc. it should stack the archived rows one after the other, so in rows #9, 10, 11, 12, 13 etc. of the archive.

The code I have used to work but then I redesigned the sheets and they stopped working. When I type archive, it deletes it from Sheet #1 but then in the archive sheet it's missing. So it's "sending" it but it's not showing up or pasting it properly. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleaned you code a bit but seems mostly fine. Isntead of using `getActiveRange` and `getActiveSheet`, use the range provided by trigger argument. This is what it would look like:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet();

  var row = r.getRow();
  var col = r.getColumn();
  var cell = s.getRange(row, col);
  var archiveStates = ["Archive", "Cancel", "Canceled", "Cancelled"];

  if (s.getName() === "Sheet" && r.getColumn() === 2 && archiveStates.includes(cell.getValue())) {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Archive"); // "Sheet Archive" is the 2nd/target sheet
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

I've also moved the way you tested for options and used strict equality (be careful with this).

### References

- [Simple triggers: onEdit(e) (Google Apps Script guides)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Strict equality (===) (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)

Comment: Thanks, this is cleaner! FYI to anyone using this, don't just duplicate the original sheet you're dealing with and designate it as an archive sheet as formatting might mess with the data transfer. I realized it was sending data to the last row (row 3000) in the archive sheet since I assume it thought the first 3000 rows were "filled out" and that it was doing the +1 input. I would start with a fresh sheet and go from there!

Answer (score 0):

Transfer data to select sheets and delete current row

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cvs = ['Archive', 'Cancel', 'Canceled', 'Cancelled'];//target sheets
  const idx = cvs.indexOf(e.value);//to get sheetname
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && ~idx && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    const vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    const tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(cvs[idx]);
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);//delete current row
  }
}
```

Sheet1:

[image]

[Bitwise Not ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. How do I make it so that if the words "Archive" or "Cancelled" are written in column #2, it sends it to sheet named "Sheet Archive"? From what I understand in what you posted, it's sending it to sheets literally called "Archive" "Cancelled" etc. when those are the trigger words that if written in column #2 of a row, it sends it to the archive sheet aforementioned. Thank you!

Comment: I have done as much as I'm interested in doing, the rest is up to you